# How to include a python for loop in output on Apache Spark with Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to include the results of a for loop in my code to the output results.

Just to give you some background:

The following code extracts text from PDFs. It then saves the results to a dataframe "mydf"

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

# field_list = ["result.content"]

document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
)

for blob in container.list_blobs():
  blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
  poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
            "prebuilt-read", blob_url)
  result = poller.result()
  print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
  print ("document contains", result.content)
  for page in result.pages:
      print("----Analyzing Read from page #{}----".format(page.page_number))

mydf = result.content
```

I modified the code to include page numbers with the following:

```
for page in result.pages:
      print("----Analyzing Read from page #{}----".format(page.page_number))
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to include the page numbers in the output. As I mentioned, the output is just extracting the text from the pages but not giving me the page numbers with the code:

```
for page in result.pages:
      print("----Analyzing Read from page #{}----".format(page.page_number))
```

I believe this is something that I have simply overlooked.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking that may be I should the code to a function - but I'm not sure. I eagerly await your thoughts

Comment: So, basically I think I would like to return both ```for blob in container.list_blobs():``` and ```for page in result.pages:``` in the dataframe "mydf'. However, as you can see I'm only returning ```for blob in container.list_blobs(): ``` when I execute ```mydf = result.content``` Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello SO community, I really could do with some help with this one

Answer (score 0):

If your storage account has pdfs invoice data with page numbers, you can manually label page numbers using [***OCR Form Recognizer***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ2NeO4c9iI&t=458s) otherwise you can use [***official document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/try-sdk-rest-api?pivots=programming-language-python#analyze-layout).

If you are connected to blob storage, make sure to replace `formUrl` with `blob URL.` Please follow below reference it has detail explanation about ***Azure Form Recognizer***.

**Sample Code:**

[image: Ref1]

**Reference:**

https://pypi.org/project/azure-ai-formrecognizer/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/try-sdk-rest-api?pivots=programming-language-python#analyze-layout

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/concept-layout

Comment: Bhanunagasai, thanks for this. While this looks good, the main result I'm looking for is to output the results to a dataframe. At the moment, you sample just prints on the results to screen. I think I need to replace the print statement with 'return' to get the results into a variable, but I'm not sure. I hope I'm making sense